Joining multiple tables with last as left join
I'm on Sybase ASE 16 and attempting to mix an inner join with a left to get matching rows from the first two tables while "adding data" from the third if it's present.
Schema:
Events



id
guid
other_id
eventType
date




1
1234
5
greeting
2024-10-10


2
1234
5
greeting
2024-10-12


1
9876
10
reject
2024-11-09


2
9876
10
reject
2024-11-11



Contracts



id
guid
other_id
user
isHappy




1
2345
5
Bob
0


1
9234
10
Jane
0


2
9234
10
Jane
1



Occurences



id
guid
interactions




1
9876
1


2
9876
2


3
9876
5



What I'm looking to get out are events that happened on (or after) 2024-11-11 for a specific eventType where the user isHappy and then add in the number of interactions if they exist (null otherwise). The query should only look at the highest id per guid in each respective table though I don't know quite how to work that with a left join on the last table.
So if I were looking at eventType=reject and date=2024-11-11, I'd expect



id
date
other_id
isHappy
user
interactions




2
2024-11-11
10
1
Jane
5



Whereas if I were looking at eventType=greeting and date=2024-10-11, I'd expect



id
date
other_id
isHappy
user
interactions




2
2024-10-12
5
0
Bob
null



The below is what I have and it's returning, seemingly, the correct join between the first two tables, but with the left join it's just dumping the Occurences table into the results.
select e.id, e.date, e.other_id, c.isHappy, c.user, o.interactions
from Events e,
    Contracts c,
    Occurences o
where e.other_id=c.other_id
    and e.eventType='reject'
    and e.guid*=o.guid
group by e.guid
having e.id=max(e.id) and e.date >= '2024-11-11'


When you join, the cardinalities between tables are typically 1:1, 1:N, or N:1. However, in your case you seem to have M:N. There are multiple ocurrences of the same value other_id in both tables (e.g. 10). This will produce a cross join that will probably generate invalid results.

what are you trying to accomplish with group by e.guid having e.id=max(e.id)? sure, ASE allows this type of non-ansi group by/having by but you're just asking for problems with this type of non-ansi coding; also 'curious' is the the listing of e.date >= '2024-11-11' in the having clause as opposed to it being part of the where clause

please update the question to include the (wrong) results generated by your query (for both of your test cases); also of help would be the basic create table and insert commands; any primary/unique/foreign keys and/or unique indexes may be of interest in understanding the data and relationships (aka joins) between tables

where the user isHappy - did you leave this out of your query? I'm assuming this would be coded as (where) isHappy = 1 in which case the 2nd example shouldn't return any data, right? or does isHappy=1 apply to whether or not you need to look for occurences?

could a single query match on multiple rows from events with different guid values? if 'yes' then please update the question with an additional example (and sample data) showing such a case

First, write queries to look at the highest id per guid in each respective table, then you can use them as subqueries; that should eliminate some of the somplexities. Also doesn't Sybase support LEFT JOIN, ... ON syntax?
